# スマホアプリでPDFを表示させたい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

Monacaでスマホのアプリを作っています。

ある会場図をPDFで表示させたいのですが、どのようにさせたらよいでしょうか？

試しに下記にしてみたら、Couldn't load plug-in が表示されました。

```
<ons-page>
    <object data="img/map.pdf" id="info_map" type="application/pdf">/object>
</ons-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

対象がiOSだけであれば[Inappbrowserプラグイン](http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/inappbrowser/)を使えば開けると思います。
Androidもサポートするのであればちょっと難易度が上がりそうですね。

---- Androidユーザーではないため、以下全て動作未確認です -----

こんな感じにしてGoogleDocsで開くなどの方法があるようです（詳細は下記の参考リンクを参照してください）。

```
window.open(encodeURI('https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=<pdfuri>'), '_blank', 'location=yes,EnableViewPortScale=yes')
```

また、まだbeta版のようですが[cordova-plugin-document-viewer](https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer)はAndroidもサポートしているみたいです。

参考：[Not able to launch a pdf file in inappbrowser in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304729/not-able-to-launch-a-pdf-file-in-inappbrowser-in-android)

ローカルのPDFを開くのであれば[FileOpener](https://github.com/don/FileOpener)とかを使用すると良さそうです。

Answer (score 1):

ご回答をありがとうございます。

Androidで出来ました。

ただ、ローカルのPDFを開きたいので、FileOpenerを試してみようと思いますが、ちょっと敷居が高そうです。

ありがとうございます。

Comment: FileOpenerを試してみました。  
  
Cordovaコアプラグインで、下記をインポートしました。  
  
https://github.com/don/FileOpener.git  
  
次に、index.htmlに下記のように記述しました。
  
    var localUrl = "";  
  
    localUrl = monaca.baseUrl;  
  
    localUrl = localUrl.replace(/index.html/g,"");  

上記でパスを取得して、ng-click="push(2);で開くようにしました。  
  
    $scope.push = function(e) {  
  
        if(e == "2") var ref = window.open(localUrl + "img/map.pdf");  
  
    }  
  
AndroidではPDFのアプリが開くのですが、  
「このファイルはアクセスできません。場所又はネットワークを確認し、もう一度実行してください。」  
とメッセージが出てしまいます。  
  
iOSの方は、PDFが開きましたが、元のアプリに戻れませんでした。  
  
もう少しいじってみます。

Answer (score 1):

もしMonacaのwebview内にpdfを表示したいのであればMozillaの[PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)が使えるかもしれません。

ただ、webviewは[limited support](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-support)のようです。

Comment: ご回答をありがとうございす。  

調べてみます。